# Is there a way to specify dependencies for a newly created sourceset in gradle?

Tags: java, dependency-management, gradle

In gradle I have created a new `sourceSet` for service testing like this:

```
sourceSets{
    servicetest{
        java.srcDirs = [//path to servicetests]
    }
}
```

This source set depends on TestNG, so I was hoping to pull the dependency down by doing something like:

```
dependencies{
    servicetest(group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '5.8', classifier: 'jdk15')
}
```

Unfortunately this returns an error. Is there any way to declare a dependency for a specific `sourceSet` or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recent Gradle versions automatically create and wire configurations 'fooCompile' and 'fooRuntime' for each source set 'foo'.

If you are still using an older version, you can declare your own configuration and add it to the source set's compileClasspath or runtimeClasspath. Something like:

```
configurations {
    serviceTestCompile
}

sourceSets {
    serviceTest {
        compileClasspath = configurations.serviceTestCompile
    }
}

dependencies {
    serviceTestCompile "org.testng:testng:5.8"
}
```

Comment: That's good to know, but unfortunately im tied to gradle 0.9.2 for now

Comment: When you say recent, as of what version? This does not seam to work for Gradle 1.4.

Comment: > "Recent Gradle versions automatically create and wire configurations 'fooCompile' and 'fooRuntime' for each source set 'foo'" -
 Does that work for kts scripts as well?

Answer (score 4):

The following works for Gradle 1.4.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

sourceSets {
    serviceTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/servicetest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/servicetest/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: '3.0.7')

    serviceTestCompile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE')
    serviceTestCompile(group: 'org.testng', name:'testng', version:'6.8.5')
}


task serviceTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs TestNG Service Tests"
    group = "Verification"
    useTestNG()
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.serviceTest.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.serviceTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```